# Error 440 "Array Index out of Bounds"

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to download an Excel attachment with the subject keyword.

I managed to create a code but sometimes it is giving **Error 440** `"Array Index out of Bounds"`.

The code got stuck in this part.

```
If Items(i).Class = Outlook.OlObjectClass.OlMail Then
```

Here is the code

```
Sub Attachment()  
    Dim N1 As String
    Dim En As String
    En = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))
    saveFolder = En & "\Desktop\"
    N1 = "Mail Attachment"

    If Len(Dir(saveFolder & N1, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir (saveFolder & N1)
    End If

    Call Test01

End Sub

Private Sub Test01()

    Dim Inbox As Outlook.Folder
    Dim obj As Object
    Dim Items As Outlook.Items
    Dim Attach As Object
    Dim MailItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Filter As String
    Dim saveFolder As String, pathLocation As String
    Dim dateFormat As String
    Dim dateCreated As String
    Dim strNewFolderName As String
    Dim Creation As String

    Const Filetype1 As String = "xlsx"
    Const Filetype2 As String = "xlsm"
    Const Filetype3 As String = "xlsb"
    Const Filetype4 As String = "xls"

    Dim Env As String
    Env = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))
    saveFolder = Env & "\Desktop\Mentor Training\"

    Set Inbox = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    'If Inbox.Items.Restrict("[UnRead] = True").Count = 0 Then
     '   MsgBox "No Mentor Training Mail In Inbox"
     '   Exit Sub
    'End If

    Filter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived" & _
        Chr(34) & " >= '4/2/2017' AND " & _
        Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:hasattachment" & _
        Chr(34) & "=1 AND" & Chr(34) & _
        Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:read" & _
        Chr(34) & "= 0"

    Set Items = Inbox.Items.Restrict(Filter)

    For i = 1 To Items.Count
        If Items(i).Class = Outlook.OlObjectClass.olMail Then
            Set obj = Items(i)
            Debug.Print obj.subject
            For Each Attach In obj.Attachments
                If Right(LCase(Attach.fileName), Len(Filetype1)) = Filetype1 Then 'For searching only excel files
                    dateFormat = Format(obj.ReceivedTime(), "dd-mm-yyyy hh-mm")
                    Attach.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "(" & dateFormat & ")" & " " & Attach
                End If
                If Right(LCase(Attach.fileName), Len(Filetype2)) = Filetype2 Then 'For searching only excel files
                    dateFormat = Format(obj.ReceivedTime(), "dd-mm-yyyy hh-mm")
                    Attach.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "(" & dateFormat & ")" & " " & Attach
                End If
                If Right(LCase(Attach.fileName), Len(Filetype3)) = Filetype3 Then 'For searching only excel files
                    dateFormat = Format(obj.ReceivedTime(), "dd-mm-yyyy hh-mm")
                    Attach.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "(" & dateFormat & ")" & " " & Attach
                End If
                If Right(LCase(Attach.fileName), Len(Filetype4)) = Filetype4 Then 'For searching only excel files
                    dateFormat = Format(obj.ReceivedTime(), "dd-mm-yyyy hh-mm")
                    Attach.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "(" & dateFormat & ")" & " " & Attach
                End If
                obj.UnRead = False
                DoEvents
                obj.Save
            Next

        End If
    Next
    MsgBox "Attachment Saved"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was my understanding that arrays in vba started at 0 by default. So if there is only one item in the list it will be located at Items(0). And since your for statement starts by looking at Items(1) it will throw that error. Changing it to:

```
For i = 0 To Items.Count - 1
```

should work I believe.

Comment: No, all Outlook collections (including Items) are 1 based, not 0.

Answer (score 2):

The filter may return zero items.

```
Set Items = Inbox.Items.Restrict(Filter)

If Items.Count > 0 then

    For i = 1 To Items.Count
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for setting up multiple dot objects simply use

**`If Items(i).Class = olMail Then`**

You may also wanna set your objects to nothing, once your done with them...

```
    Set Inbox = Nothing
    Set obj = Nothing
    Set Items = Nothing
    Set Attach = Nothing
    Set MailItem = Nothing
End Sub
```