# Outlook VBA error 440: “Array Index out of Bounds” or "Automation error"?

Tags: vba, error-handling, runtime-error

I have an Outlook VBA project under Office 2016.
When running a given `Sub`, I got an `Outlook VBA error 440: “Array Index out of Bounds”` (I could not isolate a minimal, reproducible case yet).

OTOH, [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/aa264975(v=vs.60)) and many other sources state that error 440 is used for `"Automation error"`.
Moreover, if I issue in the immediate window `Err.Raise(440)` I get an `Automation error`.
This seems quite strange to me.
I would expect a given value of `Err.Number` to be associated with a single values of `Err.Description`.
My generic question is then (regardless of my particular case):

**Can the same value of `Err.Number` be associated with two different values of `Err.Description`? Under what circumstances?**
I could not find official documentation dealing with this apparent ambiguity.

PS: This OP has two close votes for "unclear what you're asking"...
I guess I could not have stated my question more clearly.

Comment: are you getting different error messages in the same test case?

Comment: How big is this sub. is it possible to post the source code for the sub here. Also if you step through the sub, are you able to locate the line throwing the error.

Comment: @JamesLingham - No. I all cases where I got this at runtime, it was `Array Index out of Bounds`.

Comment: @Alok - No. It wouldn't be possible. But besides the code itself, I couldn't yet find a systematic way of generating the error. My project moves emails/conversations among folders, so whenever I run it successfully, my emails have changed.

Comment: @sancho.s when the error pops up, do you get a "debug" option?
By the sounds of it, there is a mistake with the logic and it is trying to access a member of an array which isn't there anymore.

as you said the macro moves emails, im guessing you remove an item from the array / collection, which makes the indexs in the array shift and the last ones unreachable.

could you provide some code to show how the loop is defined, and roughly what sort of action is executed?

Comment: Is it possible to provide the pseudo code flow here. I am assuming you are using an array variable within a loop, which at some stage gives you the error on a specific condition.

Comment: Just a guess - It is probably somehow referencing to the Outlook object and this object is using some .Net error handling. When it is translated to VBA, it takes the VBA error handling, but the description stays because it is more descriptive - [see here similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43417521/error-440-array-index-out-of-bounds)

Comment: @sancho.s For a definite answer, you'll need to post the portion of your code that's causing the problem, and any other code and background information related to it.  **(See "[mcve]".)**  We can only guess at your issue. It sounds to me like you're referring to a part of an array that doesn't exist (like Index #11 in an array with an upper bound of 10).

Comment: @ashleedawg - I agree an MCVE helps quite a bit for testing purposes. Nevertheless, I guess the answer to my generic question about which `Err.Description` (`“Array Index out of Bounds”` or `“Automation error”`) is associated with `Err.Number` `440` is independent of my particular case.
See edit.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar project I am working on and received this error when I was moving a folder of emails and one of the emails was contained in the folder was in 'draft'.